# Joining multiple tables ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SELECT *
FROM STORE
     ,MATERIAL
     ,STOREBIN
     ,VENDOR
     ,MATERIALPRICE
     ,SD
WHERE STOREBIN.STOREBINID(+) = SD.STOREBINID
AND SD.VENDORID = VENDOR.VENDORID(+)
AND MATERIAL.MATERIALID = MATERIALPRICE.MATERIALID(+)
AND STORE.STOREID = SD.STOREID
```

I have this simple query here, but i want to change the (+) notations into joins, how would this be possible? I was thinking:

```
RIGHT JOIN SD ON STOREBIN.STOREBINID = SD.STOREBINID
LEFT JOIN VENDOR ON VENDOR.VENDORID = SD.VENDORID
LEFT JOIN MATERIALPRICE ON MATERIALPRICE.MATERIAID = MATERIAL.MATERIALID
WHERE STORE.STOREID = SD.STOREID
```

But that hardly seems right because i need to join each table onto different tables.

Comment: The original query has 6 tables but only 4 conditions; which means that 1 table is in 'cross join' (cartesian product); are you sure it is correct? `MATERIAL and MATERIALPRICE` are not related to any other table.

Comment: I didn't post the full query because it is quite long, so I posted only the part I needed help with. I'm not sure how to do the joins when there are two different tables on each join. Can I just join them like how i did in the second query? And yes, I forgot to modify some of the table and column names, oops, sorry for that.

Comment: You can definitely use the new syntax; you seem to have started correctly, but you don't have all the join conditions required (MATERIAL and MATERIALPRICE join results are not related to anything else) so we can't comment if the new condition is equivalent to old. Old may not produce a syntax error, because it accepts all missing join conditions as 'cross joins' but the new syntax needs explicit cross joins. You have to have a join clause integrating every table to some other. I don't understand your comment 'hardly seems right because i need to join each table onto different tables'

Comment: I think i understand what you mean, so if i were to add a relation between MATERIAL and STORE
`AND MATERIAL.MATERIALID = STORE.MATERIALID`, 
the new syntax would serve the same purpose as the old one if the added line was also in the old syntax?

Comment: yes, complete the conditions; you can definitely write your query using the new notation (it has been around for a long time). Try to use just INNER joins, and LEFT JOINS, avoid mixing LEFT and RIGHT joins in the same query, it makes it very difficult to predict the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be equivalent (if we also add the additional criteria you mentioned):

```
FROM 
    SD 
    
    INNER JOIN STORE as S
    on S.STOREID = SD.STOREID

    INNER JOIN MATERIAL as M
    ON M.MATERIALID = SD.MATERIALID

    LEFT JOIN STOREBIN as SB
    ON SB.STOREBINID = SD.STOREBINID

    LEFT JOIN VENDOR as V
    ON V.VENDORID = SD.VENDORID

    LEFT JOIN MATERIALPRICE as MP
    ON MP.MATERIALID = M.MATERIALID
```